# 'TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object' while trying to replace consecutive white spaces with a single space in all entries of a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame where every entry is a string value and a given entry may contain consecutive white spaces. For example:

```
import re
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a--b','c  d'], 'col2':['e   f','g---h']})
print(df)
```

Output of `print(df)` (this is the initial `df`):

```
   col1   col2
0  a--b  e   f
1  c  d  g---h
```

I want to replace any consecutive white spaces with a single space in *all* the entries of `df`. So in this example, `'c  d'` (with two consecutive white spaces) should be replaced with `'c d'`, and `'e   f'` (with three consecutive white spaces) should be replaced with `'e f'`.

**Approach 1**:
I get the correct result using `df.replace`, like so

```
# Approach 1 - works fine
df = df.replace('\s+', ' ', regex = True)
print(df)
```

Output of `print(df)` (this is the correct result expected):

```
   col1   col2
0  a--b    e f
1   c d  g---h
```

**Approach 2**:
However, I get `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object` while using `df.transform`, like so

```
# Approach 2 - gives TypeError
df = df.transform(lambda s: re.sub('\s+', ' ', s))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
...
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/re.py", line 210, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

**Approach 3**:
I get `ValueError: Transform function failed` if I do

```
# Approach 3 - gives ValueError
df = df.transform(lambda s: ' '.join(s.split()))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
...
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 227, in transform
    raise ValueError("Transform function failed") from err
ValueError: Transform function failed
```

So where am I going wrong with the Approach 2 and 3?
Asking because the `df.transform` seems more powerful for transforming each cell in a DataFrame and will need that in my project for more complex transformations. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) for element wise processing, because both function working with scalars:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda s: re.sub('\s+', ' ', s))
print(df)
   col1   col2
0  a--b    e f
1   c d  g---h
```

---

```
df = df.applymap(lambda s: ' '.join(s.split()))
print(df)
   col1   col2
0  a--b    e f
1   c d  g---h
```

Method [`DataFrame.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) processing columns like `Series`, so it failed.

You can rewrite second solution with [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html) for processing columns (`Series`):

```
def f(x):
    #test - processing column
    #print (x)
    return x.str.split().str.join(' ')

df = df.transform(f)
print (df)

   col1   col2
0  a--b    e f
1   c d  g---h
```

Comment: Great, thank you for the nice explanation! I like the `applymap` approach. Using your explanation, one-liner for the `transform` approach: `df.transform(lambda s: s.str.split().str.join(' '))`

Comment: @tikka - yes, it was main for debug `print (x)` what cannot be used in `lambda` function.